# Static Force Directed Graph links not correct length

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to create a static force directed graph. One that loads without any animation in. Here's what I'm trying to emulate: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139

I have the following D3 graph:

```
var width = $("#theVizness").width(),
    height = $("#theVizness").height();

var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#ff0000", "#fff000", "#ff4900"]);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("#theVizness").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var loading = svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "loading")
    .attr("x", width / 2)
    .attr("y", height / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Loading...");

d3.json("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5772230/ForceDirectData.json", function (error, json) {
    var nodes = json.nodes;
    force.nodes(nodes)
        .links(json.links)
        .linkDistance(function (d) {
            return d.value * 1.5;
        })
        .friction(0.4);

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(json.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")              
        .style("stroke-width", 1);

        var files = svg.selectAll(".file")
        .data(json.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "file")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return color(d.colorGroup);
        });
    var totalNodes = files[0].length;

    files.append("title")
        .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

    force.start();
    for (var i = totalNodes * totalNodes; i > 0; --i) force.tick();
    force.stop();

    nodes[0].x = width / 2;
    nodes[0].y = height / 2;

    link.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

    files.attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("class", function(d){
            var classString = "file"

            if (d.index === 0) classString += " rootFile";

            return classString;
        })
        .attr("r", function(d){
            var radius = 10;

            if (d.index === 0) radius = radius * 2;

            return radius;
        });

    loading.remove();
});
```

Here's my data: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5772230/ForceDirectData.json

```
{
    "nodes":[
      {"name":"File1.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File2.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File3.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File4.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File5.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File6.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File7.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File8.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File8.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File9.exe","colorGroup":0}
    ],
    "links":[
      {"source":1,"target":0,"value":10},
      {"source":2,"target":0,"value":35},
      {"source":3,"target":0,"value":50},
      {"source":4,"target":0,"value":50},
      {"source":5,"target":0,"value":65},
      {"source":6,"target":0,"value":65},
      {"source":7,"target":0,"value":81},
      {"source":8,"target":0,"value":98},
      {"source":9,"target":0,"value":100}
    ]
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/dua5oo3r/)

From my understanding of the bl.ocks page, this graph is running the `tick` method a certain amount of times. But my issue is the lengths of my links between the nodes are not proportionate to what I have in my JSON file.

I've opted for the static graph because I did not want to have the graph animate in, like in the [standard graph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).

### Why are my links to the nodes nor correctly proportioned to match my JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question.

Is this what you mean?

```
var width = $("#theVizness").width(),
    height = $("#theVizness").height();

var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#ff0000", "#fff000", "#ff4900"]);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("#theVizness").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var loading = svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "loading")
    .attr("x", width / 2)
    .attr("y", height / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Loading...");

d3.json("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5772230/ForceDirectData.json", function (error, json) {
    var nodes = json.nodes;
    force.nodes(nodes)
        .links(json.links)
        .linkDistance(function (d) {
            return d.value * 1.5;
        })
        .friction(0.4);

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(json.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")              
        .style("stroke-width", 1);

        var files = svg.selectAll(".file")
        .data(json.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "file")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return color(d.colorGroup);
        });
    var totalNodes = files[0].length;

    files.append("title")
        .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

    force.start();
    for (var i = totalNodes * totalNodes; i > 0; --i) force.tick();


    nodes[0].x = width / 2;
    nodes[0].y = height / 2;

    link.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

    files.attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("class", function(d){
            var classString = "file"

            if (d.index === 0) classString += " rootFile";

            return classString;
        })
        .attr("r", function(d){
            var radius = 10;

            if (d.index === 0) radius = radius * 2;

            return radius;
        });
    force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    files.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });

    loading.remove();

  });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxtngawc/)

Comment: This doesn't exactly solve my issue, but is helpful. Would you mind commenting on what you changed? I'm still learning D3 and am getting familiar with its features.

Comment: I have revised my question. Hopefully it is clearer now.